# Template overloading ostream operator

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am trying to pretty print an STL container. What I am trying to is to print elemets of a container separated with a delimiter.
However I have came across a couple of problems.

**1. g++ vs VC++**

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const vector<string>& v) {
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<string>(o,","));
}

int main()
{

    vector<string> s_v;
    s_v.push_back("one");
    s_v.push_back("two");

    cout << s_v;

}
```

g++ (gcc version 4.4.0 on mingw32) can compile it an works fine. VC++ (Visual Studio 9) can not compile this code.

```
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\ostream(653): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)'
1>        with
1>        [
```

**why is this? Is this code illegal? or it is just VC++ beign VC++?**

---

**2. Unused template variable breaks compilation.**

if now I add a template to the ostream like this (it is not used, just sitting there)

```
template <typename T>  // <----- Here
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const vector<string>& v) {
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<string>(o,","));
}

int main()
{

    vector<string> s_v;
    s_v.push_back("one");
    s_v.push_back("two");

    cout << s_v;

}
```

**gcc can not match the operator anymore.**

```
    error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << s_v'

and a lot more candidates...
```

**Why? the template is unused. Should it matter?**

---

**EDIT: This is solved. I had to return o;**

**3. Used template**

```
template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const vector<T>& v) {
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(o,","));

    return o; // Edited
}

int main()
{

    vector<string> s_v;
    s_v.push_back("one");
    s_v.push_back("two");

    vector<int> i_v;
    i_v.push_back(1);
    i_v.push_back(2);

    cout << s_v;
    cout << i_v;
}
```

**If I know use the template type. g++ can compile it but then terminates with an exception.**

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
  what():  std::bad_cast
```

VC++ is just sitting and watching gcc do all of this. Doesn't compile any of them.

Can someone please clarify this things for me? Thank you.

Comment: Define your operator in std namespace. You'll see the difference

Comment: If the compiler can't infer the type of a template argument, you have to provide it yourself. So if you have `template<typename T> void Foo() { ... }`, you need to use `Foo<Type>()`. Obviously, you can't do that when you overload an operator. When you _do_ use `T`, the compiler is able to infer its type, and this is why it works.

Comment: Also, your last example [runs fine](http://ideone.com/mLJcTI) on ideone. You might want to add `return o;` to your `operator<<` though. This would most likely crash your program if you did `cout << s_v << i_v`.

Comment: @PiotrNycz _Don't_ ever define an operator in `std::` unless it involves a type you've defined somewhere.  Otherwise, the code is illegal.

Comment: I have tried defining it in std (the third version). However it still throws an exception.

Comment: @Curious I can't reproduce the error.  Once I've fixed the obvious errors (missing includes, missing `std::`, missing return), it works with my system (VC++ 11).

Comment: @zneak. Thank you. What a noobish mistake. Now it doesn't throw anymore. So that is solved. Can you explain to me why the second version can not compile?

Comment: @JamesKanze: Actually, you can't ever add any overload to the `std` namespace. You can only add specializations of existing templates.

Comment: @Curious, that's because of overload resolution of templated functions, as explained in my first comment. The only one I'm not sure about is the first example, but that might be because you're missing includes or something.

Comment: @Curious: That's because the compiler has no way of deducing `T` from the function arguments (after all, no function parameter is defined in terms of `T`, so what should `T` be?). If you're thinking "who cares, `T` is unused anyway!", then the answer is that the compiler always cares. If *you* don't care, then you just shouldn't put it there (or you should provide a default value for it)

Comment: @AndyProwl Correct.  Good point.  You can't even add additional overloads for an existing function, unless they are explicit specializations of a function template.

Comment: @AndyProwl One usually assumes the correct headers.  But his symptom sounds somewhat similar to what happens when you forget a header in at least some versions of VC++, so it might be worth considering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PREMISE:**

First of all, the code is illegal because it misses a `return` statement (which is likely what is causing the exception that gets raised in the third version):

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const vector<string>& v) {
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<string>(o,","));
    return o; // <== THIS ONE WAS MISSING
}
```

This injects undefined behavior to your program. Per Paragraph 6.6.3/1 of the C++11 Standard, in fact:

> [...] Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; **this results in undefined
>   behavior in a value-returning function**.

**Concerning your first question:**

Once that is fixed, your code is fine, and the implementation of the Standard Library that is shipped with VC9 probably has a bug.

In fact, the compiler should look up for eligible overloads of `operator <<` in the namespace of the arguments (`std`) and in the namespace where the call is being made (the global namespace). As long as your operator is defined in the global namespace *and* the statement `cout << s_v` is in the global namespace, overload resolution should succesfully pick your overload.

**Concerning your second question:**

> Why? the template is unused. Should it matter?

That's simple: the compiler has no way of deducing `T` from the function arguments, so unless you specify it explicitly, this will result in a compilation error. However, specifying the template argument explicitly would mean do something like the following, which is close to non-sense:

```
::operator << <void>(std::cout, s_v);
```

In C++11 you could specify a default argument for `T`, which would make the function call legal, bug then again, for what purpose?

**Concerning your third question:**

When `T` is used in the type of at least one of the function parameters in a deduced context, the compiler will allow to deduce it from the function arguments (in this case, it will deduce `T = std::string`, and you don't have to specify it explicitly.

**CONCLUSION:**

So to sum it up: after adding the necessary `return` statement, the first and third versions of your program are legal and make sense, while the second is not and does not.

Comment: Concerning the code he actually posted for the first question: it won't compile with any compiler, because of missing includes.  I've seen strange overload resolution with VC++ when includes are missing: including `<iostream>` might provide some (but not all) of `<string>`, so some things work, but others don't.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Right, I assumed the OP imported the correct headers and all the necessary ones, but it's true this can't be told for sure since the preliminary part is missing from the question's text

Comment: I am using std; and I have the proper includes.

Comment: The problem was the return, and then the second part as explained by both of you.

Comment: @Curious: This is not relevant to your problem, but having a `using namespace std;` is considered a bad programming practice, because it can easily lead to name clashes. You should replace that with *using declarations* (e.g. `using std::cout`) when practical, or if you really have to add a `using namespace std;`, then make sure it is in a function scope and not at global scope

Comment: Ya I know. this was just an experiment. I didn't want to write std:: everywhere. BTW in your opinion is this a good way to print containers. Is there some other _elegant_ way of doing this? It needs to be somehow generic. I have a lot of vectors ( containing different types) and I don't want to write ostream for each of them.

Comment: @Curious: The third version should be fine with vectors of different type

Comment: @Curious It's generally not a good idea to provide `<<` for containers, since depending on the context, they will need to be formatted differently.  (And using `ostream_iterator` doesn't work, because its second argument is a terminator, not a separator.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Not sure what you mean here. The Standard calls it "delimiter"

Comment: The defined semantics are those of a terminator.  It is appended after every output, not inserted between outputs.  In practice, this makes it almost useless except for `"\n"`.  Or you can output to a `std::ostringstream`, then remove the last terminator from the resulting string.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Oh, all right, now I see what you mean. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

1. As posted, your code shouldn't compile with any compiler.
   You're missing includes, and a lot of `std::`.  What I *suspect*
   is happening is that you don't have all of the necessary
   includes; in particular, that `#include <string>` is missing,
   and that g++ picks it up indirectly.  Which is curious.  The
   problem is usually the inverse: that VC++ picks up a lot of
   extra includes.  At times, however, only partially (so you might
   end up knowing about `std::string`, but not about the non-member
   functions associated with it, like `operator<<`).  Without
   seeing your actual includes, however, it's difficult to say.
2. The compiler can only perform overload resolution on
   functions, not on function templates.  Before starting overload
   resolution, it tries to instantiate an function templates with
   the correct name.  Successful instantiation results in
   a function, which it adds to the overload set.  But how is it
   supposed to instantiate your function template.  It has no way
   of knowing what to use for `T`.  So it doesn't instantiate
   (template argument deduction fails), and no instance of it finds
   its way into the overload set.
3. I don't see anything immediate here.  After adding the
   missing return in the `operator<<`, it compiles and runs
   correctly on VC++.

Comment: I am using std; and I have the proper includes. However it is odd that it works with VC for you. It still doesn't for me. The third proper version.